# Pinned application has wrong title

Tags: c#, .net, windows

When I pin my application from windows explorer, the version info is appended to the application name like so:

[image]

But when I pin my application while it is running, the version information is missing:

[image]

How can I control this behavior?

Comment: What is the `AssemblyInfo.AssemblyTitle` value ?

Comment: It contains the application name, but it does not contain any version information.

Comment: Might be a cache issue, what if you change this value, is the version information left in the pin bar ?